# ¿Cómo puedo resaltar en negrita el resultado de una operación o función?

Tags: r

Estoy intentando sin éxito convertir el resultado de aplicar una operación en R en negrita, sin éxito. Lo que estoy probando es lo siguiente:

```
a<-40

ifelse(a<50, a%>%as.character(font=2), a)
```

otra opción que había testeado es:

```
ifelse(a<50, paste('<B>a</B>'), a)
```

Entiendo que esto no funcione porque lo pegará como un string, sin detectar el valor intrínseco de 'a')

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que, todo valor de `a<50` se resalte en negrita, es decir, resaltar el valor 40?

Comment: Bienvenido Roberto, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] veas [ask] y como hacer una [mcve], eso te dará una idea de este sitio. Por otro lado, dónde vas a desplegar este código HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Tu segunda opción estaba bastante cerca. La función `paste()` no funcionó porque debes dejar a `a` fuera del string.

Te dejo aquí abajo mi solución:

```
a <- seq(20, 60, by = 10)

ifelse(a < 50, paste("<B>", a, "</B>", sep = ""), a)
```

Podrías también `paste0()` en lugar de `paste()` para no tener que especificar `sep = ""`.

```
ifelse(a < 50, paste0("<B>", a, "</B>"), a)
```

El resultado con cualquiera de estas dos opciones sería:

```
[1] "<B>20</B>" "<B>30</B>" "<B>40</B>" "50" "60"
```

Que impreso en HTML (vía Rmarkdown, por ejemplo), mostraría los números inferiores a 50 en negrilla.